# How do you cast a filtered list of HttpRequestHeaders from Request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, visual-studio-2017

I'm attempting to filter my list of headers that was returned by `Request.Headers`:

```
var validHeaders = (HttpRequestHeaders)Request.Headers.Where(header => ValidHeaders.List.Contains(header.Key.ToUpper()));
```

[image]

I am getting the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]]'
>   to type 'System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders'.'

**How do I cast a Request.Headers.Where expression into a HttpRequestHeaders?**

Comment: When you apply the `Where` clause, it changes to an enumeration and cannot be casted to a `HttpRequestHeaders` class. You would have to create a new instance, traverse the filtered collection and add the items to the newly created instance

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do. There is some code being blocked in the image by the popup so can't tell.

Comment: i'm attempting to generate a new request message from the existing Request, but filtering out headers that are not in my ValidHeaders static class list

Comment: And what do you do with the filtered list? Add it to a new request? if yes then just enumerate the valid headers and add it to the request headers. The popup is blocking so can't tell what the method that creates the request is expecting

Comment: yes i simply add it to a new httprequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply the `Where` clause, it return an enumeration of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>` and cannot be cast to a `HttpRequestHeaders` class. You would have to create a new instance, traverse the filtered collection and add the items to the newly created instance.

```
var validHeaders = Request.Headers.Where(header => ValidHeaders.List.Contais(header.Key.ToUpper()));
//create GET request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
//Add the valid headers to the new request
foreach(var header in validHeaders) {
    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
}
```